# Visual Studio 2013 Not Displaying

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using the VS2013 on a windows 8.1 to learn Programming Windows from a book I bought, programming windows 6th edition. I am trying to use VS2013 to build and run the following cs code

```
class FirstProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, .NET Framework!");
    }
}
```

It compiles correctly according to the debug, but it takes me to a new window titled "FirstProgram.Window". Which, is the name of my program, but nothing displays on the screen.

Comment: you are using Console Application ?

Comment: Try adding a `System.Console.Read();` after the `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, .NET Framework!");` line. Its possible that the program exits immediately after the output is written in the console.

Comment: If you're using a WinForms/WPF application the console output (`System.Console.WriteLine()`) is redirected to the output window of VS. You can press `Ctrl + Alt + O` to open it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `Main` method ends directly after `Console.WriteLine`, thus closing the console window. Add a call to `Console.ReadKey()` to make the window hang waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

The output actually gets written to that Window. Try adding a new line to your code

```
public static void Main()
{
Console.WriteLine("Hello, .NET Framework!");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.Read();
}
```

Or, use `Ctrl + F5` to start your console app.

Comment: That is what I am using to start it, but it takes me to a grey screen with no text on it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you created a windows form,If you just want to show something on the screen write.

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your message");
```

Console.WriteLine will print output to Console window. If you are creating console application refer to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Below menioned Code to see the Output

```
 System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, .NET Framework!");

 Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#

### CONSOLE APPLICATION

1. try using `Ctrl + F5` to run application!
2. or simply add any of `Console.Read();` or `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of your code!

example:

```
class FirstProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, .NET Framework!");
        /* your code goes here! */
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```